# MyEclipse does not deploy jars into WEB-INF/lib directory

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I import an existing Maven project into Eclipse,and i deployed it into tomcat.When I took a glance at the folder /WEB-INF/lib I have found no JAR files.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.bookshop.main</groupId>
  <artifactId>BookShop</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-framework</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>BookShop</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

quote "eclipse project right click -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly -> Add -> Java Build Path",it's not help.

Do you have an idea?Thanks.

btw:i also got the following error messages when i redeploy it:

could not be redeployed because it could not be completely removed in the undeployment phase.

Comment: So, after the Deployment Assembly change, your deployment assembly shows a line for Maven Dependencies, with a deploy path of "WEB-INF/lib"? Are there any errors in the project? What release of MyEclipse?

Comment: @Tony Weddle  Ok,it's done.Because of my dependency cannot found in central repository.the Error is: <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-framework</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>   why?

Comment: I don't see such an artifact in a maven repository. So it's not surprising that it can't be found.

Comment: @Tony Weddle  i copied it from http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Error is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I don't see such an artifact in a maven repository.Sorry.